# Encase each item inside List<Widget> with a Container

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of Widgets, and I would like to wrap each item inside that list with a Container widget. Take this code as example:

Before:

```
List<Widget> content = [
  Text('Hello'),
  Text('World'),
  Text('Please'),
  Text('Help'),
];
```

After:

```
List<Widget> content = [
  Container(child: Text('Hello')),
  Container(child: Text('World')),
  Container(child: Text('Please')),
  Container(child: Text('Help')),
];
```

Is there a way to do it programmatically, without actually wrapping all items separately?

Comment: Not sure about your use case but what about using a list view builder inside a container?

Comment: I want to wrap each child inside a Column with a Container.

Comment: I will update my answer accordingly but not sure if I would suggest that

Comment: `content = [for (var textWidget in content) Container(child: textWidget)];`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of map() to make a new list from your list.

example:
List newList=  content.map((textWidget)=>Container(child: textWidget)).toList();

maybe this can help you to get your result.

Answer (score 0):

You can map all the element and put inside Container.
for example,

```
List <Widget> newContents = content.map((text)=> Container(child: text)).toList();
```